# Azure DocumentDB will move from global to regional meters

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

DocumentDB users are receiving this email saying that from 1 February they will be charged based on the region in which their data resides and it is all clear so far.

Moreover the mail said: "the resource GUIDs for DocumentDB will also change" and there is a link to a "[GUID Mapping](https://azure.microsoft.com/it-it/support/guids-migration-documentdb/?WT.mc_id=azurebg_email_Trans_987_Customer)".

Could someone explain better this thing? I've not understood if the GUID is relative to the single document, the Subscription or anything else. What is this GUID and what is its meaning? I don't know if I really need to make changes to my application and what type.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I've understood what GUID is. I think that is the id of your DocumentDB Subscription and it needs for billing.
In fact, you can find it here:

- Go to billing area inside your Azure Dashboard
- Download and open a billing item
  [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNnG8.png)
- See row "Data services" in this file and you'll find the GUID

On the other hand, I don't know if you really need to make changes to your application.